# Can't set text or drawable because of unresolved references in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-adapter

I'm new to Kotlin and I try to learn it by writing simple app launcher on it using this Java guide: https://parallelcodes.com/create-android-launcher-program/
So far so good, but I'm stuck with some "Unresolved references" errors, and I know I do something wrong, but can't figure out what exactly, as I don't understand Kotlin syntax very well.
I've tried probably everything I found in Google, as well as rewriting code here and there. Seems like newbies often face my problem and there is a lot of that kinda questions on StackOverflow.

So here are errors:

```
viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(appInfo.icon) // Unresolved reference: icon
viewHolder.label.text = appInfo.label // Unresolved reference: label
viewHolder.name.text = appInfo.name // Unresolved reference: name
```

Here is entire MainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var apps: List<AppInfo>? = null
    private var gridView: GridView? = null
    private var adapter: ArrayAdapter<AppInfo>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        loadApps()
        loadListView()
        addGridListeners()
    }

    private fun loadApps() {
        val packageManager = packageManager
        if (apps == null) {
            apps = ArrayList()
            val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null)
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
            val availableApps: List<ResolveInfo> = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0)
            for (ri in availableApps) {
                val appinfo = AppInfo()
                appinfo.label = ri.loadLabel(packageManager)
                appinfo.name = ri.activityInfo.packageName
                appinfo.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
                (apps as ArrayList<AppInfo>).add(appinfo)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun addGridListeners() {
        val packageManager = packageManager
        gridView!!.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
            val intent: Intent? = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apps!![i].name.toString())
            this@MainActivity.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun loadListView() {
        gridView = findViewById(R.id.gridview)
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = object : ArrayAdapter<AppInfo>(this, R.layout.apps_view, apps!!) {
                override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
                    var convertView = convertView
                    val viewHolder: Any?
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.apps_view, parent, false)
                        viewHolder = ViewHolderItem()
                        viewHolder.icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_icon)
                        viewHolder.name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name)
                        viewHolder.label = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_label)
                        convertView.tag = viewHolder
                    } else {
                        viewHolder = convertView.tag
                    }
                    val appInfo = apps!![position]
                    viewHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(appInfo.icon)
                    viewHolder.label.text = appInfo.label
                    viewHolder.name.text = appInfo.name
                    return convertView!!
                }

                inner class ViewHolderItem {
                    var icon: ImageView? = null
                    var label: TextView? = null
                    var name: TextView? = null
                }
            }
        }
        gridView!!.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

Here is activity_main.xml in case it's needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:background="#000"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Here is AppInfo class:

```
class AppInfo {
    var label: CharSequence? = null
    var name: CharSequence? = null
    var icon: Drawable? = null
}
```

And here is apps_view.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_icon"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_label"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#361b1b"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="0sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it's clear. What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an Unresolved reference error because of this line:

```
val viewHolder: Any?
```

Here `viewHolder` has type `Any?` and when you are referencing, for example, to `label` property `viewHolder.label` it shows the error because `Any` doesn't have such property.

To solve the problem use `ViewHolderItem` type for `viewHolder`:

```
val viewHolder: ViewHolderItem
```

Comment: That's it! And how didn't I guess... By the way, that ": Any?" explicit variable call was suggested by Android Studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ViewHolderItem is an inner class, which it's fields cannot be access from the outer class.
for creating a model class in kotlin use data class like this :

```
data class ViewHolderItem(val p1 : String, val p2 : Int, ...)
```